# Wi-Fi Direct and simulateous broadban connection?

Tags: wireless, wpa-supplicant, wifi-direct, p2p

Does any have any tips/experience/links that would show the configuration to enable a Wi-Fi Direct connection and normal Wi-Fi (broadband to a Access Point) at the same time?

From the Wi-fi.org website;
"... Simultaneous connection to a Wi-Fi Direct-certified group and an infrastructure network is an optional feature."

See; http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/can-a-device-simultaneously-connect-to-a-regular-wi-fi-network-and-a-group-of

Thanks
TM